# Jquery Validation in Rails 6.0.2 using webpacker

Tags: jquery-validate, webpack-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I have built a sample blog application with subscribers. The tech used for this application

- Ruby:      2.6.3
- Rails:     6.0.2
- Webpacker: 4.2.2

I am validating my Subscriber form with Jquery-Validation, to make sure the user enters a valid email.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#new_subscriber").validate({
      rules: {
        "subscriber[email]": {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

This works locally but doesn't get compiled, So later understood and added

```
yarn add jquery

#in environment.js
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  }),
)

yarn add jquery-validation
```

Not sure how to call it in **envionment.js**

My current package.json

```
{
  "name": "SampleBlog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

The validation is not working. Later I have created a home.js in javascript/packs and written this code

```
require("jquery")
require("jquery-validation")

$("#new_subscriber").validate({
  rules: {
    "subscriber[email]": {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

Included this in .html.erb as well

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home' %>
```

No help getting the console error, validate is not a function

Any feedback will be very helpful

Comment: same issue with me as well

Comment: Did you got an answer?